# ECS unable to create log stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to set up a new ECS Service and my Task isn't creating the log streams for the service. Instead, I get the following error message at the top of the ECS Task screen:

[image: error image]

I have the following set up as the IAM permissions for the execution role:

```
  MyExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchFullAccess
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "ECR"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - ecr:BatchGetImage
                  - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
                  - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                Resource: "*"
        - PolicyName: "Logs"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:Create
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutDestination
                Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*"
        - PolicyName: "GetSecrets"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ssm:GetParameters
                  - kms:Decrypt
                  - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/*"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:*"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:kms:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:key/*"
```

Any help figuring this out so I can get logs from the container would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a policy for `Logs`.

The managed policy you add `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` already contains the [permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy.html).

Maybe you have to check if you correctly set `executionRoleArn` and not the `taskRoleArn` that are two differents kind of role for ECS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html